# 3-Way dimmer switch, dimming both locations?

Tags: dimmer-switch

So I have two 3-Way dimmer switches.  I am able to switching the lights on or off from each location, but I can only dim from one of the switches.  Did I do something wrong, or is it only possible to dim from one dimmer switch or can I dim from both dimmer switches.

Comment: Can you post the brand and model of switches hat you are using? Every manufacturer does things slightly differently and it may be possible but we don't know what you are working with.

Comment: Yeah -- we need make and model to go further here